# userToken and passwordText add in SOAP client using java

Tags: java, soap-client

I want to add username and password as a header to soap client in java by using PasswordText usernameToken. When I load WSDL in SOAPUI it does not automatically add this header, I put the header manually. The SOAPUI request looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx1CC.jpg)

Now I am making SOAP client in Java and it requires header info, I don't know how to add a header to the client in java. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?